# Problems printing bibliography with \nocite{*} and biblatex/biber

Tags: biblatex, biber

I'm having trouble getting the entire bibliography to show up when using `\nocite{*}`.

Here's an example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{test.bib}
@ARTICLE{Doe2009,
author = {Jon Doe},
journal = {Transactions on Stuff},
month = 03,
number = {3},
pages = {1--11},
title = {{Example 1}},
volume = {5},
year = {2009}
}

@ARTICLE{Doe2010,
author = {Jon Doe},
journal = {More Transactions on Stuff},
month = 05,
number = {4},
pages = {1--11},
title = {{Example 2}},
volume = {7},
year = {2010}
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{test.bib}

\begin{document}

\section{Test}

%\cite{Doe2010}

\nocite{*}
%\nocite{Doe2009}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

The bibliography won't show up at all for me when it is like this. However, if I cite something in the document, for example I place `\cite{Doe2010}` somewhere in there, the entire bibliography will then print. Or if I add `\nocite{Doe2009}` the entire bibliography will also print. What am I missing here? Why won't `\nocite{*}` work on its own?

Update: I am using MiKTeX 2.9 with latest updates and TeXstudio.

[image]

Comment: The code you gave works perfectly for me.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not possible to replicate the problem. The MWE works correctly.

Comment: @Guido I suspect it is my setup then. I've updated my question with some additional info.

Comment: Try to remove all auxiliary file (`.aux`, `.bbl`, `.log`) and try to compile again. Also try from the command line.

Comment: @Guido Removing the auxiliary files didn't work. However, I switched programs and used Texmaker instead. The default setting of `PdfLaTeX + View PDF` gives the same result. But if I switch it to `PdfLaTeX + Bib(la)tex + PdfLaTeX(x2) + View PDF` it will work! I couldn't figure out how to do that in TeXstudio so I'm going to stop using it. That said, I still don't completely understand these build commands/order and what they mean (specifically why PdfLaTeX is run again after and why twice). I would greatly appreciate it if you could explain it so I can educate myself.